# Saving huge bigram dictionary to file using pickle

Tags: python, file, dictionary, pickle

a friend of mine wrote this little progam.
the `textFile` is 1.2GB in size (7 years worth of newspapers).
He successfully manages to create the dictionary but he cannot write it to a file using pickle(program hangs).

```
import sys
import string
import cPickle as pickle

biGramDict = {}

textFile = open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'r')
biGramDictFile = open(str(sys.argv[2]), 'w')


for line in textFile:
   if (line.find('<s>')!=-1):
      old = None
      for line2 in textFile:
         if (line2.find('</s>')!=-1):
            break
         else:
            line2=line2.strip()
            if line2 not in string.punctuation:
               if old != None:
                  if old not in biGramDict:
                     biGramDict[old] = {}
                  if line2 not in biGramDict[old]:
                     biGramDict[old][line2] = 0
                  biGramDict[old][line2]+=1
               old=line2

textFile.close()

print "going to pickle..."    
pickle.dump(biGramDict, biGramDictFile,2)

print "pickle done. now load it..."

biGramDictFile.close()
biGramDictFile = open(str(sys.argv[2]), 'r')

newBiGramDict = pickle.load(biGramDictFile)
```

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
for anyone interested i will briefly explain what this program does.
assuming you have a file formated roughly like this:

```
<s>
Hello
,
World
!
</s>
<s>
Hello
,
munde
!
</s>
<s>
World
domination
.
</s>
<s>
Total
World
domination
!
</s>
```

- `<s>` are sentences separators.
- one word per line.

a biGramDictionary is generated for later use.
something like this:

```
{
 "Hello": {"World": 1, "munde": 1}, 
 "World": {"domination": 2},
 "Total": {"World": 1},
}
```

hope this helps. right now the strategy changed to using mysql because sqlite just wasn't working (probably because of the size)

Comment: if you are going to be messing with BIG files, why not use a database? also, i see you do for loop over the same file 2 times, that may be redundant and adds to processing cost. why not describe what you are doing with sample input files ?

Comment: ghostdog74, you see 2 for statements, but there is only one loop over the file :) Iterating over a file is just reading lines (from actual position), it does not seek to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Simply try [sqlitedict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlitedict) (your Python dict backed by DB on disk, not RAM).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pickle is only meant to write complete (small) objects. Your dictionary is a bit large to even hold in memory, you'd better use a database instead so you can store and retrieve entries one by one instead of all at once.

Some good and easily integratable singe-file database formats you can use from Python are [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) or one of the [DBM variants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html). The last one acts just like a dictionary (i.e. you can read and write key/value-pairs) but uses the disk as storage rather than 1.2 GBs of memory.

Comment: Sqlite is a fully relational database, while Berkeley DB is not, just key/value. If it's just storing, I think Berkeley is a better option, while if you want to make some queries and store the information in more organized way, sqlite it's more appropiate.

Comment: BerkeleyDB is rather fickle and difficult to manage, especially with larger amounts of data. Even for a single string->string store (which is what BerkeleyDB would be) I would use SQLite, which will take care of all the BerkeleyDB management.

Comment: SQLite does not act like a dictionary.

Comment: The Python page for the bsddb moddule (http://www.python.org/doc/2.6/library/bsddb.html) says that it is deprecated.  Is there another non-deprecated Python option for a BSD DB?

Comment: http://www.python.org/doc/2.6/library/persistence.html lists a number of data persistence modules. The `gdbm` module looks very similar and still supported, I'd go for that one.

Comment: your database suggestion was adequate. although he had to use mysql because SQLite just wasn't cutting it.

Comment: @JoãoPortela It would be good to update your question with why "***SQLite just wasn't cutting it.***" and I wonder if a decade later **SQLite3** is still playing second fiddle now that it is used in Google Chrome and Firefox on Linux platforms.

Comment: I would love to, but this was so long ago I'm not sure anymore. I think the whole process (inserting and latter querying) ended up being too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the whole data in memory? You could split it in naive ways like one file for each year o each month if you want the dictionary/pickle approach.

Also, remember that the dictionaries are not sorted, you can have problems having to sort that ammount of data. In case you want to search or sort the data, of course...

Anyway, I think that the database approach commented before is the most flexible one, specially on the long run...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [buzhug](http://buzhug.sourceforge.net/) instead of pickle. It's a pure Python solution, and retains very Pythonic syntax. I think of it as the next step up from shelve and their ilk. It will handle the data sizes you're talking about. Its size limit is 2 GB per field (each field is stored in a separate file).

Answer (score 0):

If your *really, really* want to use a dictionary like semantics, try SQLAlchemy's `associationproxy`. The following (rather long) piece of code translates your dictionary into *Key,Value-Pairs* in the `entries`-Table. I do not know how SQLAlchemy copes with your big dictionary, but SQLite should be able to handle it nicely.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, Unicode, UnicodeText
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker, scoped_session, Query, relation
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import column_mapped_collection
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///newspapers.db')

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.bind = engine

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine))
session = Session()

newspapers = Table('newspapers', metadata,
    Column('newspaper_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('newspaper_name', Unicode(128)),
)

entries = Table('entries', metadata,
    Column('entry_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('newspaper_id', Integer, ForeignKey('newspapers.newspaper_id')),
    Column('entry_key', Unicode(255)),
    Column('entry_value', UnicodeText),
    UniqueConstraint('entry_key', 'entry_value', name="pair"),
)

class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        for key, value in kw.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    query = Session.query_property(Query)

def create_entry(key, value):
    return Entry(entry_key=key, entry_value=value)

class Newspaper(Base):

    entries = association_proxy('entry_dict', 'entry_value',
        creator=create_entry)

class Entry(Base):
    pass

mapper(Newspaper, newspapers, properties={
    'entry_dict': relation(Entry,
        collection_class=column_mapped_collection(entries.c.entry_key)),
})
mapper(Entry, entries)

metadata.create_all()

dictionary = {
    u'foo': u'bar',
    u'baz': u'quux'
}

roll = Newspaper(newspaper_name=u"The Toilet Roll")
session.add(roll)
session.flush()

roll.entries = dictionary
session.flush()

for entry in Entry.query.all():
    print entry.entry_key, entry.entry_value
session.commit()

session.expire_all()

print Newspaper.query.filter_by(newspaper_id=1).one().entries
```

gives

```
foo bar
baz quux
{u'foo': u'bar', u'baz': u'quux'}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of using SQLite3 in python down the road. I'm not sure what the relationship is to `sqlalchemy` in your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I captured images from `http://coverartarchive.org` and although slow downloading so many images, `pickle` had no problem with 155 MB:

```
$ ll
total 151756
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick 155208082 Oct 10 10:04 ipc.pickle
```

As I move beyond downloading images for just one CD, I'll come back and update this answer with larger pickle limits. Unfortunately I haven't found anywhere that states the pickling limits...